# How to access an exported Angular library component into my application?

Tags: angular, angular8

I created an **Angular library** called *my-library* which has an exported module called *DummyModule*.
This module has an exported *DummyComponent* and is exposed from *my-library* through the file *public-api.ts* like so :

```
export * from './lib/dummy/dummy.module';
```

If I import my *DummyModule* into my *AppModule*, I can successfully use my *DummyComponent* into my *app.component.html* template. So far so good!

But for a some reason that I'm not aware of, if I try to import my *DummyComponent* inside my app.component.ts file and try to use it in the code, I get the following compilation error:

```
"export 'DummyComponent' was not found in 'my-library'
```

How can I access my exported library component into my application and reference it in the components code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export the `DummyComponent` explicitly in your *public-api.ts* file:

`export { DummyComponent } from './lib/dummy/components/dummy/dummy.component';`

Comment: My component is declared and exported as expected!

Comment: Have you tried explicitly exporting the component in the `public-api.ts` file?

Comment: I did it like so :
    
    export {DummyComponent} from './lib/dummy/components/dummy/dummy.component';

My IDE is okay with it, but the compiler throws the same error.

Comment: Okay my bad, I rerun the build and it finally seems to pass compilation!
But I still don't understand why I need to explicitly expose my components since they are already part of a module, isn't it a bit redundant ?

Comment: In your `AppModule`, are you importing the `DummyModule` from the library?

Comment: Yes I do! And it causes no troubles when I use my component in my app.component.html template! I guess the "import" statement made in a .ts file is not aware of modules importations, which means you can only "import" a component only if it was explicitly exported through the "export" statement in your library's public api.
Thanks Rafael !